# Is there a quality difference between YouTube videos on Chrome vs. Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video, rendering

YouTube videos played back in Chrome seem not as sharp as compared to Firefox (on Windows XP).

Is this just my imagination or is there a technical reason for this?

It seems like Firefox spawns a separate process to handle Flash. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of two similar frames to support your claim? For what it's worth, I don't see *any* difference.

Comment: This question was asked back when Flash Player was used to play videos, using hardware acceleration if available. Since that time, they've completely switched over to using HTML5 built in browser video playback. Not all browsers have the same supported codecs. If you want to see a list of all the video formats and quality levels available, you can use a command line tool like this: youtube-dl -F "youtube video URL"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quality is dependent upon the quality you select in the flash player. Perhaps you have an extension that selects a higher-quality default in firefox than in chrome, but the same levels of quality are available in both.

(For what it's worth, chrome has always run flash and other extensions in their own processes.)

Comment: I do not recall anything about video quality setting

Comment: @ajreal http://i.imgur.com/d3L6i.png

Comment: Yup, I think probably I just over thinking...